# Keyboard layout indicator in LXQt shows same the symbol for different variants

Tags: keyboard-layout, indicator, lxqt

Running LXQt on Kubuntu 18.04. Had installed it using `sudo apt-get install lxqt` command. I am really liking it. Super fast.

One problem, though, is about the keyboard layout indicator. I use US Dvorak. So, I added the keyboard layout. But the keyboard layout indicator for both normal and Dvorak keyboards is US. So, no use.

How do I assign a different symbol to Dvorak keyboard?

Comment: In relation to the warkaround suggested in my answer below: why do you need US Dvorak? Is that in order to write in a different language than English? In that case, you could add also a second layout for that same language in the way I did. - In case you need Dvorak just for English: why do you need the standard US  English layout then, and why don't you remove it?

Comment: @cipricus I am much faster typing using Dvorak layout. I use it to type English only. But I also need to keep QWERTY because the computer is also used by others who are not proficient in Dvorak.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot**, I think, with the keyboard indicator of the LXQT panel, but I am posting this in order to suggest a workaround that would make the keyboard indicator usable.

---

Not all keyboard-layout indicators (and they are usually desktop-environment-specific) provide a ***different symbol for the different variants of the same language*** (in some they are differentiated by a number, a dot, an inverted comma, etc), and even fewer allow you to ***customize*** the symbol for each keyboard (isn't that only present in KDE?)...

This problem with Lxqt is [also present in elementaryOS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8119/170).

I imagine such situations could be flagged as bugs.

---

**My workaround** is this:

Add other two keyboard layouts, and **use them as indicators for the layout that comes after them**. Example for my case: I do not use US Dvorak, but US International with dead keys, along US standard, French, and a version of Romanian.

[image]

"US English" and "US English International with dead keys" are both indicated as "US" by the keyboard indicator, but **I have ordered them in such a way that I can easily identify them when cycling** with Alt-CapsLock or the mouse-click: ***US after RO*** is the standard version (easy to remember because I can use US keyboard to write in Romanian if I want, or RO keyboard to write in English), ***US after FR*** is the US international version with dead keys (easy to remember because these two layouts can both be used to write in French).

I have to confess that in my case I haven't added those two supplementary keyboard layouts for this specific purpose: I needed them anyway. But they made accessible this solution which, I hope, would suggest to you a workaround and make the keyboard usable.